# Expression Blend 4 Right to Left Issue

Tags: silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

I have recently installed Expression Blend 4 and created a test Silverlight 4 project.
When I set the main page FlowDirection to RightToLeft the designer won't change the direction but if I run the application it will be displayed correctly.

Is this a bug or do I have to do something?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you were the one who also put the post at the microsoft social site ([available here](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en/blend/thread/2f5bbca4-f6b2-47a6-a73a-b3008834aad1)) but since it took me a while to find it, I'll also put the response here:

Unni Ravindranathan - MSFT:

> We do not support RTL on the design-surface, so what you are seeing is currently by design (the value that you set is ignored). We hope to be able to support it in the future, however.

Let's hope they would!